# Angular + firebase - limit data entry queue?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning angularJS and firebase. 
Currently I have a very simple app that takes in a list of tasks. User inputs `text` with their `tasks`.

[image: current firebase structure]

*(current structure)*

How can I limit the data entry to the list to 3 tasks max and queue it so when the 4th data comes in, it automatically deletes the 1st data? (first data in first data out)

Example:

```
tasks
|
|----- task1              + --(task 4)
|----- task2
|----- task3

=

tasks
|
|----- task2
|----- task3
|----- task4
```

Comment: I'd just synchronize 4 items with `limitToFirst(4)` and then delete number 4.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out this link if you have not already and then applying the logic to achieve your goal. [Angularfire - Firebase query / sync first x items in document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259562/angularfire-firebase-query-sync-first-x-items-in-document)